# How to implement video chat using opentok sdk in android?

Tags: android, opentok

i am new open tok,
i have gone through OpenTok Android Tutorial. In this tutorial both, Publisher and Subscriber are the same user. How can I subscribe another user to this Session? In other words, How can I connect 2 different android devices?
please guide me how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Use Same session with different publisher keys in different device For peer to peer video streamings.